# C++ header files are not being found

Tags: c++, bash, environment-variables

Context: I am building some code for an embedded board. It calls for installing the Xilinx tools, the Linaro toolchain and then invoking a setup bash script in the development board build directory (let's call it setup.sh).

If I do not run setup.sh , I can then build one of the lower level libraries, which has it's own configure script (./configure) which calls the usual ./bootstrap script. In this scenario ./bootstrap , g++ in this case says it can find sstream (the C++ stream header). Ok. Fine.

When I run the setup.sh script (at the top level), g++ then says it CANNOT find sstream. So somehow the g++ environment is changed somehow, and it is this I am trying to figure out.

The output in this erroneous case is

```
g++ has streams in std:: namespace
g++ does not have sstream
g++ does not have strstream.h
g++ does not have strstrea.h
```

I am trying to debug this to find out what g++ thinks it is doing and why it cannot find the sstream header. What are some ways to look at what the g++ include and libstdc++ library paths are set to? What environment variables control the behavior of gcc/g++?

## #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Xilinx ships their own gcc toolchain with their products.

Just add the `-I` compile file to point to the proper includes path.
Try to search for the header files inside Xilinx's `/opt` path, so you don't have a mismatch between the header version and the library version.

Makefile's usual env variables are:

```
# C Compiler: GNU C Compiler
CC = gcc    
# Linker: GNU Linker
LD = ld    
# C++ Compiler: GNU C++ Compiler
CPP = g++
```

Also check

```
CFLAGS
CPPFLAGS
LDFLAGS
```

Check if $CC is set after you execute setup.sh.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will look in these places. I want to know where the headers and includes are being redefined. I am also trying to figure out WHAT the setup script is doing such that it causes gcc to search for the scripts differently.

Comment: Yes ... I have found an issue. It looks like it is finding the Xilinx stuff instead of the standard gcc stuff ... 

./a.out 
./a.out: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.4/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./a.out)

Comment: The question I have/uncertain about is does g++ search the $PATH for the libstdc++ ...

Comment: gcc linker looks for libraries on multiple places: [editing...] On a default path hardcoded when gcc is compiled (probably the /opt path in your case), then env variable LIBRARY_PATH, and the paths passed by the -L flag... An elf binary will have a hard coded path to the binary it was linked to at compile time. If it can't find it it'll try to search that library on LD_LIBRARY_PATH.